# efficency of the following switch statement?

Tags: javascript, performance

I've got a 3-4 second lag time in my program and I'm suspecting it is my switch. It's a switch like so...

```
case "aword":
//do something
break;
case "aword2":
//do something
break;
```

The switch has about 20-25 cases + breaks. I'm wondering would this account for my lag time? If so, how would you suggest correcting it?

switch condition is...

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    switch(request.req)
    {
```

What makes me suspect the switch is...

I have a print statement just before the switch call and it prints fine. Then they next print is in the switch when it finds the case before the `//dosomething`. This leads me to believe that the problem lies with finding this one case.

Comment: Don't 'suspect' these things. Split it out into a function, then use a profiling tool (which you'll find built into Firebug, Chrome's Dev Tools, etc)

Comment: I think switching is better than `ifelseifelseifelse`. Why do you think this is the problem? Only 20 switches shouldn't be too hard. Maybe it is the string comparison? Try switching on integers?

Comment: I have been using Chrome Dev tools to see, It's not telling me much I've used print statements and everything right now points to the switch.

Comment: `switch` is one of the simplest and oldest programming language constructs and should be one of the best optimized. A 20-25 case `switch` will almost certainly not take 3-4 seconds.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say that a switch like this, executed once, is **not** the performance problem. Is the switch embedded in a loop? What is the loop doing? What do the switch cases do (that is, what does "do something" actually involve)?

Comment: Are you sure the time critical data is not in `//do something` ?

Comment: I've updated my question to answer some of your questions.

Comment: Re your updates: I would not use print statements as a means for collecting timing data. Even setting breakpoints would give you a better coarse-level sense of timing than using print statements. But I'd start with firebug's profiler, rather than relying on either print statements or breakpoints.

Comment: I've been using Chrome Web dev tools. But they're no use. It's not telling me anything. I need to use Chrome since it's part of a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the switch for sure. I made an alternative solution and it made no difference. Back to the drawing board on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the 'case' part is not the problem. Simple string comparison doesn't take such a long time (3-4s). But how is your 'switch'-condition looks like? Probebly is there any time consuming stuff...

Comment: I've added it to the question